# in-app purchase to use any feature of application

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to put in-app purchase before user use any feature of application ?
means user can allow to use application after doing in-app purchase only.

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly forbidden by Apple and your App will be rejected.
If you want to do so, so make a paid app.

Comment: My application is paid and is so expensive, But my client is getting lose, because same apple id is used to download same application.I want to restrict to use one time only.

Comment: I don't disbelieve you and hope it isn't allowed but can you provide the Apple review guideline this would get rejected under just to back your statement up with. Thanks

Comment: @SeemaSharma It wouldn't make a difference if the In-App Purchase is purchased under the same Apple account then you would need to provide it to them on whatever device they use it on as well.

Comment: I will keep consumable in-app purchase

Comment: This is not allowed by Apple, even if you use a consumable. The consumable IAP should be restorable on all the device owned by the user.

Comment: A consumable purchase wouldn't be allowed as the content you are offering isn't consumable.

Comment: There is no precise "rule" that say it will be rejected, but since it goes out of the purpose of in-app purchase it should be rejected.
In-app purchase are done to provide "additional" features in your app.
An app must have even basic feature once downloaded.

You can read this **In-App Purchase allows you to sell additional features and functionality from within your iOS and OS X applications.** from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have a screen where the only item on screen is a button to trigger an in app purchase.

If the user has already completed the purchase, then you instead load a different screen.

This, however, sounds like a horrible way to "trick" users into downloading an apparently free app. Thankfully however, it seems [this is disallowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221070/916299).

Comment: will apple approve that ?